# Testfor command procuding error in 1.11 snapshots?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've been making a map for 1.10 and it's going great, but 1.11 shows great mobs to use for it. However, most things have channged in command syntax. For example, `/kill @e[type=ArmorStand,r=6]` is now `/kill @e[type=Armor_Stand,r=6]`

What about `/testfor`? I can't find a way to `testfor` a player to stand on a block and give them an effect.
[image]

What's is going on in this image is that a redstone clock is running into this command `/testfor @a[1117,20,507,r=1]` (if I was to stand on them cords the comparator would turn on and power that command block), but it only works in 1.10... from 1.11 snapshots, I've seen some errors of it, like it now needs to have `{}` at the beginning and end of it. (e.g. `/testfor @a{[1117,20,507,r=1]}`)

It's still not working, though, so does anyone know how to get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to changes in the way the 1.11 snapshots parse selector arguments, you now have to specify `x=`, `y=` and `z=` before your coordinates; the `@a[#,#,#,#]` shortcut no longer works unfortunately. For example:

```
/testfor @a[x=1117,y=20,z=507,r=1]
```

Comment: thx, so helpful i can finally get updating the map thx :D

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
[this may be complicated]
Take a command block,comparator.
Place a command block and type in this command:
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:iron_block -1
Now place a comparator running into the 2nd command block and type in the command you want to execute.

Or : [if you want to use it with tellraw]
Take a command block,comparator.
Place a command block and type in this command with a slight change
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:iron_block -1 /setblock    minecraft:redstone_block

make sure your x,y,z are the coordinates which will make the block execute the command.

Hope it works XD