# Help with Invalid selector argument

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I'm trying to make a testfor command, here is the command:

```
/testfor @p[7586,198,698,r=1,name=BrodieBolt]
```

My problem is that the output says:

```
Invalid selector argument: '7586'
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Minecraft : Testfor in 1.11 snapshots?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/286801/minecraft-testfor-in-1-11-snapshots)

Answer (score 3):

As of 1.11, you must specify `x=`, `y=`, and `z=` before your coordinates. Try:

```
/testfor @p[x=7586,y=198,z=698,r=1,name=BrodieBolt]
```

Comment: now its saying that it cant detect the entity "Entity '@p[x=7586,y=198,z=698,r=1,name=BrodieBolt]' cannot be found"

Comment: @Brodiebolt The error is telling you the issue: there's no player named "BrodieBolt" within 1 block of those coordinates. You need to be at the location while ensuring the command block is running.